# Azure CLI on Linux and Mac: certificate trouble

Tags: linux, macos, azure, kubernetes, azure-cli

I'm trying to follow [**this**](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure/) official tutorial on Kubernetes with Azure. I tried it both on Mac and Linux.

I can successfully login from CLI with my corporate account, but when I run `./create-kubernetes-cluster.js` in the end of the output I see

```
info:    Executing command network vnet create
info:    Using default address space cidr: 12
info:    Using default subnet start IP: 172.16.0.0
info:    Using default subnet cidr: 15
+ Looking up network configuration
error:   The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.
info:    Error information has been recorded to /home/dds/.azure/azure.err
error:   network vnet create command failed
```

What certificate this is about? Where it come from?

Here is `azure.err`:

```
[Error: The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.]
  stack: [Getter/Setter],
  code: 'ForbiddenError',
  statusCode: 403,
  __frame:
   { name: 'get__3',
     line: 47,
     file: '/home/dds/k8s/src/kubernetes/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/asm/network/networkConfig.js',
     prev:
      { name: 'create__1',
        line: 34,
        file: '/home/dds/k8s/src/kubernetes/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/asm/network/virtualNetwork.js',
        prev: [Object],
        calls: 1,
        active: false,
        offset: 4,
        col: 43 },
     calls: 0,
     active: false,
     offset: 4,
     col: 59 },
  rawStack: [Getter] }
Error: The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.
  <<< async stack >>>
  at get__3 (/home/dds/k8s/src/kubernetes/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/asm/network/networkConfig.js:51:60)
  at create__1 (/home/dds/k8s/src/kubernetes/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/asm/network/virtualNetwork.js:38:44)
  at __6 (/home/dds/k8s/src/kubernetes/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/asm/network/network.js:125:22)
  <<< raw stack >>>
    at Function.ServiceClient._normalizeError (/home/dds/k8s/src/kubernetes/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-common/lib/services/serviceclient.js:815:23)
    at /home/dds/k8s/src/kubernetes/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-common/lib/services/filters/errorhandlingfilter.js:44:29
    at Request._callback (/home/dds/k8s/src/kubernetes/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-common/lib/http/request-pipeline.js:109:14)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/dds/k8s/src/kubernetes/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-common/node_modules/request/request.js:199:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/dds/k8s/src/kubernetes/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-common/node_modules/request/request.js:1160:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/dds/k8s/src/kubernetes/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-common/node_modules/request/request.js:1111:12)
```

Could you tell me how can I fix this?

**Update**

I created a ticket for Azure support and they told me:

> I see most of the Resource Providers are not registered for your
>   subscription. Deployments (first time) done via portal register
>   resource providers automatically, however if its via PowerShell or CLI
>   we have these have to be registered (one time activity)
>   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/azure-cli-arm-commands/
>
> Please run these cmdlets to register the providers & then retry the
>   deployment

```
azure provider register –namespace Microsoft.Network
azure provider register –namespace Microsoft.Compute 
azure provider register –namespace Microsoft.ContainerService 
azure provider register –namespace Microsoft.ResourceHealth 
azure provider register –namespace Microsoft.Storage
```

I executed these commands successfully, but the result is still the same.

Comment: What kubernetes are you running? The hyperkube or the straight command line version?

Comment: Kubernetes cloned from current master branch. Exactly steps from tutorial I mentioned.

Comment: @colemickens you something about Kubernetes and Azure, maybe you know this answer.

Comment: That does not answer my questions since there are multiple solutions to run this: Hyperkube makes a difference with the command line version. If you want directions or ideas, please answer the questions in comments

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen straight command line version, not hyperkube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that you need to add the azure account as co admin in the azure subscription.

Here are some useful links how to do it:

[How to add or change Azure administrator roles](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator/)

[Changing Service Administrator and Co-Administrator when logged-in with an organizational account](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/changing-service-admin-and-co-admin/)

[Assigning administrator roles in Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-assign-admin-roles/)